# How to add multipart properties in Protege?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I am interested in multipart properties like hasParent followed by hasSpecies (denoted as`:hasParent + :hasSpecies`)

How to make it work in Protege?

Comment: create a property and add a property chain axiom axiom like `:myProperty SubPropertyOf :hasParent o :hasSpecies` - the `o` char is used to chain properties

Comment: I made it. Thank you!